# Why didn't Mickey testify before court?

Tags: plot-explanation, payback-2021

In *Payback* (2021), at 25:51 the dialog goes like this --

> Mickey: Mr. Strauss, I didn't do this. Slava sent me to the store. Ruslan killed those men.
> Strauss: Are you prepared to testify to that?

Then the movie shows that Mickey comes back home after spending six years in prison. That means, he didn't testify.

So, the question is: Why didn't Mickey testify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not stated but there seem to be a couple of reasons.

Firstly, Mickey's job is not quite 100% legitimate as he seems to be openly involved in shady stock manipulation.

Secondly, his heritage would seem to be 'old school Russian' where testifying (or co-operating with law enforcement), even at personal cost would not be something he would do, especially against someone from the same culture / heritage.

Finally, it seems pretty clear that the case against him is fairly watertight (albeit he is being framed) and taking the deal would seem to be his best option.

---

Obviously the real reason is that there would be no movies if he did testify